# Best way to store an ArrayList of bytes onto a text file on a long running app

Tags: java, android, arraylist, io, byte

I have a program that is storing bytes of data into an `ArrayList`. On average every time I write data to the file, the average data is of 460 bytes and new information once every second.  After it is done doing recording all the data I want to write it to a text file as a byte array using `FileOutputStream`. The app can run from minutes to hours.

Note: The user signals when they want to stop recording the bytes, not the system, cap, or anything else.

Is it better to store all the data into an `ArrayList` then write that information onto a text file, or is it better to write separate text files at different time intervals to avoid any conflicts?

What are the downsides of the way that I'm currently doing it?

Comment: Why do you use an `ArrayList` instead of a `BufferedOutputStream`?

Comment: Because I want to write the entire file in one go, instead of appending to it constantly. Also, I get bytes from different locations, and using the  `.add` method proves better than to to keep a global iterator

Comment: Exactly why I'm suggesting a buffered output stream, which won't write to the underlying stream constantly and it also won't consume too much memory. Can you post some code? I'm guessing you are using a `ArrayList<Byte>`? Don't see how it's better even with your comment.

Comment: I see what you are saying now :). And low memory usage was also part of the concern.